# test error:-in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working with ruby on rails and I'm having a problem while running a "ruby -Itest test/models/user_test.rb". I get an error when I make changes in the regular expression `/^[a-zA-Z0-9-]+$/` and now I am stuck in this problem and I don't know how to get over it.

My user.rb file:-

```
validates :profilename, presence: true,

uniqueness: true, format: { with: /^[a-zA-Z0-9-]+$/ , multiline: true, 

message: 'Must be formatted correctly.' }
```

Running test:-

```
$ ruby -Itest test/models/user_test.rb

DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle

Run options: --seed 50723

Running:
.....#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x4ecc8a0 @base=#<User id: nil, first_name: "sarah", last_name: "gupta", profile_name: "S_arah-1", email: "sarah089@gma
il.com", encrypted_password: "", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at
: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, @messages={}>
E..


Finished in 0.380267s, 15.7784 runs/s, 28.9270 assertions/s..

1) Error: UserTest#test_a_user_can_have_a_correctly_formatted_profile_name: ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2) test/models/user_test.rb:41:in `block in <class:UserTest>'

6 runs, 11 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

Here is the code for a_user_can_have_a_correctly_formatted_profile_name

```
test "a user can have a correctly formatted profile name" do 
  user = User.new(first_name: 'sarah', last_name: 'gupta', email: 'sarah089@gmail.com') 
  user.password = user.password_confirmation = 'welcome' 
  user.profile_name = 's_arah-1' 
  assert.user.valid? 
end
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you put the code for test name **test_a_user_can_have_a_correctly_formatted_profile_name**

Comment: code:-                           test "a user can have a correctly formatted profile name" do
      user = User.new(first_name: 'sarah', last_name: 'gupta', email: 'sarah089@gmail.com')
      user.password = user.password_confirmation = 'welcome'
      user.profile_name = 's_arah-1'
      assert.user.valid?
        
 end

Comment: Check if it is `profilename` or `profile_name`. Also, goto **test/models/user_test.rb line 41** and check what method is being called. You may not be passing some expected arguments

Comment: Ruby, can you please edit your original question to include that code?  Correct formatting makes it much easier to read.

Comment: From your question, it sounds like you had a regular expression that did not raise this error.  Can you share it, in the original post?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the answer to your question is in the file `user_test.rb`.  Try checking where `test_a_user_can_have_a_correctly_formatted_profile_name` is defined, and where it's called: according to the error, it's being called without the required one or two arguments.  I'm guessing you need to give it a test username.

Comment: This code "assert !user.valid?" work for me and it passed the test with no errors. but i don't know what exactly meaning of this code.?

Comment: `!` means "not", so if `assert !user.valid?` passes, that means the user is not valid.